# How do I link to an ID on a non org-mode file?

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to create a link inside an org-mode file to a source code file, say in C++. But I'd like the link to point to a possibly changing position in the file, so I want to use a unique identifier. For example, say the C++ file is as follows:

```
// {{{ 507ab9d0-d1a5-4fa9-97a9-d78a48a08c3d
<some content>
// }}}
```

I want to create a link that takes me to `507ab9d0-d1a5-4fa9-97a9-d78a48a08c3d`. Can this be done in org-mode? I've been looking at org-id [1], but to the lay person, it does not seem to fit this use case.

[1] https://github.com/tkf/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org-id.el

Comment: I've also been investigating on how to do this using org-transclusion, but this question refers to only plain org-mode. For org-transclusion, see https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion/issues/59

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a file link like this:

file:f1.cpp::507ab9d0-d1a5-4fa9-97a9-d78a48a08c3d

It should open the file and then search for the string you put in.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't aware of text search, this is precisely what I need! :-) https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html Cheers